# stuck while updating android in samsung GT-I9003

Tags: odin

while updating my samsung GT-I9003 using odin i removed the cable now my phone is showing a logo of a mobile and a computer. please help please

Comment: Did you already try to reboot the phone in Odin mode (via the VolumeDown+Home+Power combination)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a software corruption. Try the following steps.

1. Turn off the device.
2. Go to Android System Recovery screen.
3. Wipe data / factory reset and select delete all user data.
4. Reboot system.